# How to install external monitor?

Tags: 12.04, laptop, external-monitor

So,I have a Philips 190c monitor and an Acer Aspire 57321zg with AMD HD 4570 and I want to know how in the world I can connect those to work properly?

I connect the monitor the following occurs:

- the desktop works fine
- the login screen's resolution is 1280x768(my external monitor is using 1280x1024)
- I cannot use displays separatly(1 resolution on laptop display and 1 resolution on external monitor),I need to disable one of them, I chose to disable laptop's display.
- if I change the resolution from Amd's catalyst control center I get the following:
- the login screen's resolution is the same as the desktop's
- in the right-down corner when I go with the cursor it freezes until I go with the cursor up
- if I upgrade video driver on 1280x1024 I can see only 3/4 of the desktop 1/4(at the bottom) is black and the issues above remain.It only shows the whole desktop if i change the resolution from catalyst center but it has the downside that my mouse is freezing like before.

So to point out the obvious: I'm trying to have my display on the external monitor with 
desktop and login screen same resolution without mouse freezing or other side effects.And if possible the newest AMD driver(13.1) without the 1/4 of black screen.

Heads up: I'm not interested on how to install a driver,I know that,I don't want to know how to "plug-in" a monitor on a laptop etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could actually be more interested in installing and uninstalling drivers than you seem to think.
That is, you should try to uninstall AMD driver and test the open source driver.

As far as AMD is concerned you have legacy hardware. When people use proprietary drivers there seems to be lot of problems with hardware that falls into this category.

After removing AMD driver, run this:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-radeon
```

Reboot.
Configure your displays: System settings -> Hardware -> Displays

If everything works fine, you might even be happy.
PS! I had HD4870 and I was struggling with trying to get AMD legacy driver to work for way too long. Don't go on that road. You'll sleep better.

Comment: appearantly fresh install came with a different problem....constant errors and crashes ill try removing the proprietary driver and install the open source one.